# Storing the selected values in a hiddenfield inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater and i have some controls like dropdown and text box how can i catch the drop down selected value and the value entered in the textbox and store them in the hidden field??

It is like a formula `Left(c1+c2)*c3` the format is like this.

Comment: Use `FindControl` method to obtain reference of `control` in code-behind.

Comment: But how can i store the values inside a hiddenfield?

Answer (score 1):

**Repeater Code :**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID='myRepeater' runat="server" OnItemDataBound='myRepeater_OnItemDataBound'>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID='myHidden' runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="GeneralDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />

          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


**Code behind :**
    protected void myRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
                var myHidden = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("myHidden");

               foreach(RepeaterItem dataItem in 'myRepeater.Items)
               {
                  myHidden.Value  = ((DropDownList)'myRepeater.FindControl("GeneralDDL")).SelectedItem.Text; 

                 // Same like for Text box              
               }     
         }
```

Comment: When i add a control to the repeater it is appearing 5 times how can i prevent it??